# select one row  in a table  which doesn't exist  

Tags: sql

My sql string is like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY t.month
```

the result like:

```
ID  data month
1     0    1
2     1    2
3     2    4
4     3    5
```

I need select in ,for example,the first five month,so I need  right outer join another table,
the table is like this:

```
month
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

It's not a real table in database,
my expecting result is like:

```
 ID  data month
 1     0    1
 2     1    2
            3
 3     2    4
 4     3    5
```

how do I write this query?

Comment: What is the structure of both tables?

Comment: post your table schema and possible some data and desired result

Comment: This question is unclear, vague, and can't possibly be answered.  Please rephrase with additional information about what you're trying to do.  What is the structure of your database (and a few row samples might not hurt either)?  What is your expected result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display values that is table2 but not in table1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897722/display-values-that-is-table2-but-not-in-table1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t.month
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY t.month
UNION SELECT FOO;
```

Replace `FOO` with the value you want to append.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you mean by join. But this is the solution to one of the possible interpretations (return only those rows not contained in the other table)

```
SELECT ....
FROM table AS t
WHERE t.month not in (
    SELECT id 
    FROM month
)
GROUP BY t.month
```