# delete subject with commands sql

Tags: mysql

i have code for database for subject and commands table

i want sql statement if i am want to delete subject directly delete all commands for this subject.
my database is

```
create table if not exists subject(
S_Id INT(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName varchar(255) not null,
title text not null,
PRIMARY KEY (S_Id)
);

create table if not exists comm(
C_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
message text not null,
S_Id int not null,
PRIMARY KEY (C_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (S_Id) REFERENCES Persons(S_Id)
);
```

thanks all ...

Comment: you must read about triggers. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: Is the foreign key in comm supposed to reference s_id in the subject table, or am I missing the link between the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, you can use the [foreign key contraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) `ON DELETE CASCADE` on your referencing foreign key in `comm`. (I'm assuming here that the `S_Id` foreign key in `comm` is supposed to reference `subject`, not `Persons`);

```
create table if not exists comm(
  C_Id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
  message text not null,
  S_Id int not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (C_Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (S_Id) REFERENCES subject(S_Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When this constraint is added, any delete from `Subject` will delete the corresponding lines in `comm` automatically.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/832c0/1).

As a side note, personally I'm very careful about adding constraints like this that may alter data unexpectedly. If you have cascades set up in multiple steps, a single accidental delete may end up removing a *lot* of referencing rows.

Answer (score 0):

@Satish Sharma is right here is a link to triggers [SQL Server ON DELETE Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996643/sql-server-on-delete-trigger)
for your example

```
    CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
        ON subject
        FOR DELETE
    AS
        DELETE FROM comm
        WHERE S_Id IN(SELECT deleted.S_Id FROM deleted)
    GO
```

Comment: i take your comment and paste it to mysql i get error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax