# Automatically sync one table with another table (columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I am adding a delete feature on my application that will delete a row from Table1. It will first insert that row into Table2 and then delete it from Table1.

To get a duplication of Table1's columns for Table2, I could do this:

```
SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Table1
```

However, is there a way to have Table2 automatically get all columns from Table1 on a constant basis? The reason I ask is because Table1 will have different columns added in the future, so having to manually duplicate this into Table2 will be an annoyance. Thanks!

Comment: You need trigger to do that, check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996643/sql-server-on-delete-trigger , of course you'll probably have to modify code a bit, but that is solution for your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this:

- You could use a trigger, that would catch `DELETE` operations
- You could modify you `DELETE` statement to use `OUTPUT`

It would look like this:

```
DELETE T1
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO Table2
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

So whenever you delete something from `Table1`, these records will be added to `Table2`.

If `Table2` is supposed to be an archive table, it could have a `ArchiveDate` column, so then your statement could be potentially improved and look like this:

```
DELETE T1
OUTPUT DELETED.*, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO Table2
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

Of course I would not recommend using `*` in your SQL Queries and list your columns carefully:

```
DELETE T1
OUTPUT DELETED.Column1, DELETED.Column2, DELETED.Column3, DELETED.Column4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
INTO Table2 (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, ArchiveDate)
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

This way, you'll be able to know when that specific record was deleted.

Comment: That is one groovy statement man, didn't know that was possible

Comment: @Veljko89 Now you do! :)

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try.

Comment: @RockOn If `Table2` is supposed to be an Archive. You could potentially have a ArchiveDate column there, then you would know when delete operation was done. I'll add mini example in my answer.