# Update table after delete using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, constraints

As the title states, I'm trying to use a trigger to update a value in Table2 when a row gets deleted from Table1. My code looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Table1_DEL
    ON Table1
    FOR DELETE
AS
    UPDATE Table2 SET
        FK_Table1ID = NULL
    WHERE FK_Table1ID = (SELECT Table1ID FROM DELETED)
```

- The first error I get is with the UPDATE command and that states:
  "Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE'. Expecting EXTERNAL.
- The second error
  is with the DELETED table that I'm trying to access. This states
  "Invalid object name 'DELETED'.

Overall, I'm just trying to mimic a constraint that sets the column to null (ON DELETE SET NULL). I'm doing this because I got an error saying I might cause multiple cycles or cascade paths when trying to add the constraint.

For my code, I based it off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996970/11489532) answer.

Comment: Please note you need to handle the fact that `Deleted` might have multiple rows i.e. this `WHERE FK_Table1ID = (SELECT Table1ID FROM DELETED)` should be this `WHERE FK_Table1ID IN (SELECT Table1ID FROM DELETED)`

Comment: You should probably also add both `SET NOCOUNT ON;` and `IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted)) RETURN;` to the trigger. Little tip: if you have a FK cycle, there is a good chance that something is wrong with the design of your DB. Not always true at all, just something to think about.

Comment: I don't see how you can get that first error with the code you showed us. Are you sure this is the entire code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to have a very simple fix. I was getting the errors because I was trying to add the trigger after dropping a constraint. This is fine, but I forgot to add a GO command in between the dropping of the constraint and the creation of the trigger. My code looked like this:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT
ADD TRIGGER
```

but this was the correct solution:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT
GO
ADD TRIGGER
```

Edit: as [DaleK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127428/dale-k) has pointed out, I also need to modify the WHERE clause in case the DELETED table has multiple rows

Comment: Still, make sure you sort the `=` versus `IN` problem.

Comment: But you need to modify the condition in where clause if there is any chance to delete more than one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in SQL Server. I have just replaced (=) with (in).

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Table1_DEL
ON Table1
FOR DELETE
AS
    UPDATE Table2 
    SET FK_Table1ID = NULL 
    WHERE FK_Table1ID IN (SELECT Table1ID FROM DELETED)
```

**Example:**

```
 create table empsalary(empid int, month int , salary int);

 insert into empsalary values(1, 1, 100);
 insert into empsalary values(1, 2, 101);
 insert into empsalary values(1, 3, 103);

 create table emp(empid int, id int);

 insert into emp values(1,1);


CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Table1_DEL
ON empsalary
FOR DELETE
AS
    UPDATE emp 
    SET id = NULL 
    WHERE empid IN (SELECT empid FROM DELETED)
     

 select  * from empsalary
```

| empid | month | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 101 |
| 1 | 3 | 103 |

```
 select  * from emp
```

| empid | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

```
 delete empsalary where month=1;

 select * from empsalary;
```

| empid | month | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 101 |
| 1 | 3 | 103 |

```
 select  *from emp;
```

| empid | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afb49db968cf51f86f66f97ece2f41d5)*