# TSQL table variable in WHERE statement causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
DECLARE @user int;
DECLARE @aipNip varchar(20);
DECLARE @accessToBaseCompanies TABLE (baseCompanyId INT);

SET @user = 1;

INSERT INTO @accessToBaseCompanies (baseCompanyId) 
((SELECT c.BaseCompanyFk FROM [dbo].Companies c WHERE c.CompaniesTeamFk IN (SELECT u.CompaniesTeamFk FROM [dbo].[CompaniesTeams_Users] u WHERE UserFk = @user))
UNION ALL
(SELECT c.BaseCompanyFk FROM [dbo].Beneficiaries c WHERE c.DepartmentFk IN (SELECT u.DepartmentFk FROM [dbo].[Departments_Users] u WHERE UserFk = @user)))

SET @aipNip = (SELECT TOP 1 fc.[PureNip]
FROM [dbo].[BaseCompanies] bc
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Companies] c ON bc.Id = c.BaseCompanyFk AND c.CompanyType = 1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Payment_Partners] fc ON fc.id = bc.CompanyPartnerFk)

SELECT bc.[Id]
      ,bc.[Name] as 'BaseCompany'
      ,SUM(cd.[PaidAmountNavireo]) - SUM(cd.[GrossTotal])
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN (ps.Id = 1 OR ps.Id = 3)
  FROM [dbo].[BaseCompanies] bc
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Payment_CostDocuments] cd ON bc.Id = cd.BaseCompanyFk
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[PaymentStatuses] ps ON ps.Id = cd.PaymentStatusFk
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Payment_Partners] fc ON fc.Id = cd.PartnerFk

  WHERE bc.[Id] IN @accessToBaseCompanies

Team BY
bc.[Id],
bc.[Name]
```

@accessToBaseCompanies is not empty, why when I try execute query I get error: Incorrect syntax near '@accessToBaseCompanies'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The argument to `IN` is a value list or a subquery, not a table.  Try:

```
WHERE bc.[Id] IN (select baseCompanyId from @accessToBaseCompanies)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
WHERE bc.[Id] IN @accessToBaseCompanies
```

It should be:

```
WHERE bc.[Id] IN (select baseCompanyId from @accessToBaseCompanies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use EXISTS instead IN, usually first a more productive([SQL Server IN vs. EXISTS Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance)). Replace the

```
WHERE bc.[Id] IN @accessToBaseCompanies
```

by

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @accessToBaseCompanies a where a.baseCompanyId = bc.[Id] )
```