# update table where there is duplicate records using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to update a table but my problem is the target table has duplicate records so my update is failing for that reason. This is the error: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows.   I know when updating a table, we have to join unique keys but i cannot delete the duplicates from the table so i am looking for a work around for my situation.  The CUSTOMERTABLE is the one that has the duplicates.  Here is my query:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERTABLE
SET SERVICE = 'BILLING'
FROM
(SELECT distinct(CUSTOMER_ID)AS ACCT_ID
       ,ED.CUSTOMER_NAME
       , ED.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
  FROM CUSTOMER_RELATION ED, STG_CUSTOMER_REV TXN
  WHERE ED.CUSTOMER_ID = TXN.CUS_ID
 )AS X

WHERE X.ACCT_ID = CUSTOMERTABLE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing it with an `IN` clause:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERTABLE
SET SERVICE = 'BILLING'
WHERE CUSTOMERTABLE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN
    (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
     FROM CUSTOMER_RELATION ED
     JOIN STG_CUSTOMER_REV TXN ON ED.CUSTOMER_ID = TXN.CUS_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option, which probably has a better performance compared to an `IN` solution if `CUSTOMER_RELATION` or `STG_CUSTOMER_REV` are large tables.

```
UPDATE C
   SET SERVICE = 'BILLING'
FROM CUSTOMERTABLE C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM CUSTOMER_RELATION ED, STG_CUSTOMER_REV TXN
              WHERE ED.CUSTOMER_ID = TXN.CUS_ID AND CUSTOMER_ID = C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Why do you say that has better performance?

Comment: Check the following link for a discussion on this subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance

Comment: Fair point but don't forget the query optimizer might generate the same plan for both if it can determine they are logically equivalent based on the table definitions.

Comment: I agree there are other things to consider (indexes, stats, optimizer, etc). It's not a given it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping on the CustomerId

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERTABLE
SET SERVICE = 'BILLING'
FROM
(SELECT distinct(CUSTOMER_ID)AS ACCT_ID
       ,ED.CUSTOMER_NAME
       , ED.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
  FROM CUSTOMER_RELATION ED, STG_CUSTOMER_REV TXN
  WHERE ED.CUSTOMER_ID = TXN.CUS_ID
  GROUP BY ED.CUSTOMER_ID
 )AS X

WHERE X.ACCT_ID = CUSTOMERTABLE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
```

You need to make sure that your select return non duplicates. Try using that select without the update statement and check if the select cotains the duplicates you want to get rid off.

Comment: thanks Key, the subquery runs fine but the problem is this:CUSTOMERTABLE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, the account_number in the customer table has duplicates

Comment: @moe, if the account_number has duplicates then the update will update them all unles you add a anothere where clause distinguish them. Did you try acfrancis answer?