# Modern alternative to DELETE ... WHERE ... NOT IN (...)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Taking the following two table variables, is there any (faster/shorter/more efficient) alternative to delete any data from `@tbl_big` that doesn't exist within `@tbl_small`?  The reason is that I have a large selection of data, and based on optional parameters (in a procedure) I filter the data down further before presenting to the user.

The `userId` column is indexed in the physical table these table variable columns are populated from.

```
DECLARE @tbl_big TABLE (userID int);
INSERT INTO @tbl_big (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20),(30),(40),(60),(100);

DECLARE @tbl_small TABLE (userID int);
INSERT INTO @tbl_small (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20)

-- this deletes 30,40,60,100 from @tbl_big
DELETE FROM 
    @tbl_big 
WHERE
    (userID NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM @tbl_small));

SELECT * from @tbl_big;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12674

I did wonder whether `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT` might do this but can't figure them out.

**Update:**  `EXCEPT`/`INTERSECT` findings included as an answer.  I'm not sure if there's a shorter way from a coding perspective...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, exists or left outer join would do the trick.

```
DELETE b FROM @tbl_big b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM @tbl_small s
    WHERE s.userID = b.userID);
```

OR

```
DELETE b FROM @tbl_big b
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tbl_small s
    ON s.userID = b.userID
WHERE s.userID IS NULL;
```

Comment: +1 for NOT EXISTS, -1 for LEFT OUTER JOIN. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Amazing article. Why is `SELECT 1` used please instead of `SELECT *` as the article mentions?  Also, what are the problems mentioned in the article that could arise from duplicates/NULLs?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a proponent of the NOT EXISTS. Sometimes it depends, you can find examples on the intertubes where LEFT OUTER was more performant over not exists, especially when nesting exists statements. The `SELECT 1` vs `SELECT *` I am of the impression that either are ok, i.e. performance is not affected. I think some people are just totally anti-`SELECT *` that they choose to `SELECT 1` instead.

Comment: Accepted this answer as the comments were extremely helpful.  I'm not convinced that any alternative method is any better than the original, but it was interesting finding out.  Thank you all.

Comment: And +1 to Dave for having the best moustache on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Well this is modern :) but i'm not sure it's faster than a delete where not exists :

```
DECLARE @tbl_big TABLE (userID int)
DECLARE @tbl_small TABLE (userID int)

INSERT INTO @tbl_big (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20),(30),(40),(60),(100)
INSERT INTO @tbl_small (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20)

;with deleting as (
SELECT * from @tbl_big
except
select * from @tbl_small)

DELETE b 
FROM 
    @tbl_big b
where exists ( 
select * from deleting c where c.userID = b.userID)

SELECT * from @tbl_big
```

Comment: Thanks for that; I had not thought of using CTE's.  As with my suggestion, it looks pretty cumbersome doesn't it!

Comment: It's also slow unless you replace the `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT...)` with `WHERE userID in...`

Comment: not really, exists is faster than in as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance and i'm already limiting my results in the cte. So it means for each it will check perhaps 10-100-1000 lines (the differences) instead of a full group

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tbl_big TABLE (userID int)
DECLARE @tbl_small TABLE (userID int)
DECLARE @tbl_new TABLE (userID int)

INSERT INTO @tbl_big (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20),(30),(40),(60),(100)
INSERT INTO @tbl_small (userID) VALUES (1),(5),(10),(20)

INSERT INTO @tbl_new 
SELECT userID
FROM @tbl_big 
INTERSECT 
SELECT userID
FROM @tbl_small;

SELECT * from @tbl_new;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured `EXCEPT` out, although its not exactly easier to read!

```
DELETE
    b
FROM 
    @tbl_big b INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        @tbl_big EXCEPT 
    SELECT
        userID
    FROM
        @tbl_small) s ON s.userID = b.userID;
```

I realise now also that `INTERSECT` would actually delete the wrong half of the data (e.g. data `NOT IN @tbl_small`)