# MySQL - Update join & increment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6a2d/1) (also below should the fiddle die in future). The goal is to return all checked out items back to the items table, updating the quantity value.

```
CREATE TABLE checkout(
    id INT NOT NULL
    -- toUser, indexes, etc
);

CREATE TABLE inventory(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    quantity INT DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO inventory(quantity) VALUES(90);
INSERT INTO inventory(quantity) VALUES(42);

-- 10 values
INSERT INTO checkout(id) VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1);

-- 8 values
INSERT INTO checkout(id) VALUES(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2);

-- Return all the checked out items back to the inventory (up the quantity)
UPDATE inventory i
INNER JOIN checkout c ON c.id = i.id
SET i.quantity = i.quantity + 1;
```

After this UPDATE, I was expecting this result:

```
Inventory:
id = 1, quantity = 100
id = 2, quantity = 50
```

Instead, this was received:

```
Inventory:
id = 1, quantity = 91
id = 2, quantity = 43
```

A join returns 18 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory i INNER JOIN checkout c ON c.id = i.id;
```

I believe there is a hole in my understanding of the UPDATE operation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the question is why do you expect 100 and 50?The JOIN is ON ID there are only 2 distinct ids in inventory so 90+1 and 42+1.

Comment: @Mihai Swapping UPDATE for SELECT as `SELECT * FROM inventory i INNER JOIN checkout c ON c.id = i.id`, produces all the rows I was looking for. I then expected a walk down the rows.  Per @eggyal, that behavior is essentially undefined, and comes out looking like DISTINCT as you mention.  Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html):

> For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

In other words, since each record from the `inventory` table is joined multiple times to the `checkout` table, there is no guarantee that the value of `i.quantity` on the right-hand side of the assignment will reflect previous updates.

As [@newfurniturey suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623175), you could instead `UPDATE` from a correlated `COUNT()` subquery.  However, I'd be more tempted to define [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkout_ins AFTER INSERT ON checkout FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE inventory SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE id = NEW.id;

CREATE TRIGGER checkout_upd AFTER UPDATE ON checkout FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE inventory SET quantity = quantity + CASE id
    WHEN OLD.id THEN -1
    WHEN NEW.id THEN +1
  END WHERE id IN (OLD.id, NEW.id);

CREATE TRIGGER checkout_del AFTER DELETE ON checkout FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE inventory SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE id = OLD.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion!  I'll likely end up using it here and elsewhere.

Comment: Edit: On insert, the quantity should dec, and delete should inc.

Comment: Items may be removed from checkout that are no longer destined for inventory (such as being purchased).  With the solution above, deleting the item from checkout would place it back into inventory.  Are triggers a good case here?

Comment: @nous: I wouldn't try to deal with such business logic in the database layer of your application: rather, explicitly update `inventory` from within a higher tier.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're after, you want to "add" `1` to the `quantity` column for every record in `checkout` that has the same `id`? For instance, if there are 10 entries in `checkout` for `id = 1`, you will have `quantity = quantity + 10`...

If that's the case, you'll need to use a `group by` function in your `UPDATE` statement (instead of a `JOIN`); you can accomplish this with a sub-query and [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```
UPDATE inventory i
SET i.quantity = i.quantity + (
    SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM checkout c WHERE c.id = i.id
);
```

Results:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory;

ID  QUANTITY
1   100
2   50
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c20/1)

Comment: Would this produce a full table scan on inventory?

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement would, yes, because there is no `WHERE` clause specified. Without one, it will effectively hit every row in the table. If you want it to only do a subset, you'll need to specify a `WHERE` clause (it will be more efficient if it also has proper indexes defined, but that's a different topic)

Comment: i.e. `WHERE i.id IN (SELECT checkout.id FROM checkout GROUP BY checkout.id)`. Let's assume proper indices for our discussion, any additional critique for this `WHERE`?

Comment: @nous: That will only be significant if there are substantially more items of inventory than have ever been checked out.

Comment: @nous I wouldn't add an additional `SELECT` to the `WHERE` if you'll already be performing it in the `UPDATE` itself. If you have an index on `checkout.id`, the `SELECT COUNT(*)` from that table should be a very fast lookup; however, if you were to go with the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`, I would suggest using [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html): `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM checkout c WHERE c.id = i.id)` as it should be faster.

Comment: Thanks! [Why EXISTS is faster than IN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2065403/1464716).