# sql check if rows are subset of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

will you help my problem?  I have a tblProduct which is a bill of material for producing items with decal.  tblStock is the available decal that is in stock.  I need a query to check which product can be manufactured based on the available decal.  The product can only be produced if all the decals are available. Thanks so much in advanced

tblProduct

```
    Id      decal_1         decal_2     decal_3        
    1       111             121         144
    2       104             106         144
    3       121             144         163
    4       122             144         163
    5       (null)          163         191
    6       104             121         163
```

tblStock

```
Available_decal
111
121
144
163
191
```

Desired Output

```
Id
1
3
5
```

Note that there is a null in number 5. this complicates the matter

Comment: Please share with us the sql query that you have tried to build.

Comment: Once you start adding numbers to columns, it's usually a sign that your data model is wrong. There probably ought to be a separate table from product that contains a separate *row* for each required `decal`. This would mean that you only need two rows for product 5 and it's now easy, if and when the requirement comes along for some product to have a 4th `decal`. It also makes this query easy to write because it's now just a relational division.

Comment: @Damien I agree, the table needs to be normalized.  However it is a legacy database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IN` check should do it

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tblProduct 
WHERE 
    (decal_1 IS NULL OR decal_1 IN (SELECT Available_decal FROM tblStock))
    AND (decal_2 IS NULL OR decal_2 IN (SELECT Available_decal FROM tblStock))
    AND (decal_3 IS NULL OR decal_3 IN (SELECT Available_decal FROM tblStock))
```

Another way with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tblProduct 
WHERE 
    (decal_1 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblStock WHERE Available_decal = decal_1))
    AND (decal_2 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblStock WHERE Available_decal = decal_2))
    AND (decal_3 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblStock WHERE Available_decal = decal_3))
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work but I forgot to mention that some of the fields have a null value. how would you handle this?

Comment: @KrisAdidarma I updated the queries regarding your additional request.

Comment: great and simple solution.  My thanks.  which one is faster? the "IN" Solution or the "EXISTS" solution?

Comment: According to the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance `EXISTS` is faster :)