# Selecting rows where column in child row has particular value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say you have table A

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id int,
  attribute varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE B (
   id int,
   parent_id int,
   attribute varchar(10)
)
```

parent_id is a link to the id column in A. I would like all rows from A (all columns), if B.attribute = "Test". Note that there may be multiple B records for each A, but I only want the DISTICT A. I know I could do this, but it seems like it would not be performant.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.attribute
FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id = b.parent_id
WHERE b.attribute = "Test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally EXISTS operates faster than IN() so I usually prefer this query over others. try it out!

```
SELECT a.id, a.attribute
FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM B b
    WHERE a.id = b.parent_id
      AND b.attribute = 'Test'
);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f66ae8/2)

Answer (score 1):

Using `IN` will  perform better than your query. However,The best alternative is `EXISTS` as @John Ruddell said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736929/1923685)

```
    SELECT a.id,
       a.attribute
FROM   A AS a
WHERE  a.id IN (SELECT parent_id
                FROM   B AS b
                WHERE  b.attribute = "Test");
```

`EXISTS` is more faster because once the engine has found a hit, it will quit looking as the condition has proved true. With IN it will collect all the results from the subquery before further processing.([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance))

```
SELECT a.id, a.attribute
FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM B b
    WHERE a.id = b.parent_id
      AND b.attribute = 'Test'
);
```

Comment: way to copy my query... took you 7 minutes

Comment: If you want to use my query in your answer thats fine.. but give credit where credit is due. its not right to copy someone elses query. if you fix i'll remove my downvote :)