# Is this SQL query with an EXISTS the most performant way of returning my result?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find the following statistic: `How many users have made at least one order`

(yeah, sounds like homework .. but this is a simplistic example of my real query).

Here's the made up query

```
SELECT COUNT(UserId)
FROM USERS a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT OrderId
    FROM ORDERS b
    WHERE a.UserId = b.UserId
)
```

I feel like I'm getting the correct answers but I feel like this is an overkill and is inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way I can get this result?

If this was `linq` I feel like I want to use the `Any()` keyword....

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance

Comment: [_Your eyes can deceive you. Don't trust them._](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope)  Your query is fine.  Trust the compiler to find the optimal plan based on your data and inidices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just could use [`COUNT DISTINCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserId)
FROM ORDERS
```

This will return the number of distinct values of `UserId` appear in the table `OrderId`.

In response to [*sgeddes*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073631/sgeddes), to ensure that `UserId` also appears in `Users`, simply do a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.UserId)
FROM ORDERS b
  JOIN USERS a 
    ON a.UserId = b.UserId
```

Comment: This could work, but it assumes the `UserId` from the `Orders` table exists in the `Users` table as well.

Comment: @sgeddes I included a case for handling that if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(distinct u.userid)
From USERS u
Inner join ORDERS o
On o.userid = u.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be fine, but there are a few other ways to calculate the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USERS a
WHERE UserId IN (
    SELECT UserId 
    FROM ORDERS b
)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM USERS a
INNER JOIN ORDERS b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
```

The only way to know which is faster is to try each method and measure the performance.