# Retrieval of Unmatched rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables Order and OrderItem.
Order table has the column ID_Order and OrderItem has the foreign key FK_Order which is the value from ID_order of order table.

Now I have to create a query showing all entries from table order where no reference is in orderItem (id_order is not used as fk_order in the table orderitem).

Please let me know. I used outer joins..but they are not displaying proper results.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend using `Exist` rather than `IN` clause. Because [it will be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065403/711861)

```
SELECT *
FROM   Order o
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT *
                    FROM   OrderItem oi
                    WHERE o.ID_order = oi.ID_order)
```

Another way would be `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM   Order o LEFT JOIN OrderItem oi 
       ON o.ID_order = oi.ID_order
WHERE oi.ID_order IS NULL
```

Comment: Out of above queries which one is faster..please let me know..Thanks for the help..

Comment: This is not true - in all versions since 2008 they produce the same plan and execute identically.