# SELECT subgroup of values

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements, in-clause

Given two tables 'Draws' `(id, date)` AND 'Results' `(id, draw_id, number)` where each Draw has x results, how can I get the draws that have a subgroup of numbers within their results?

```
Draws
-----------------
Id | Date
-----------------
1  | 2015-01-20
2  | 2015-01-22
-----------------

Results
--------------------
Id  | Draw | Number
--------------------
1   | 1    | 13
2   | 1    | 15
3   | 1    | 22
4   | 1    | 36
5   | 1    | 45
6   | 2    | 11
7   | 2    | 15
8   | 2    | 22
```

How can I get the draw that has `(15,22,45)` within its results? (In the example draw #1)

Comment: Do you mean return the draw(s) that have 15, 22 and 45 in the results?  IE only draws that have all 3?

Comment: @Fred yes only draws that have all 3 even if they have more.

Comment: Your selected answer doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch by Fred, this will return the correct results:

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    Draw AS d
INNER JOIN Results AS r1 ON r1.Draw = d.ID AND r1.Number = 15
INNER JOIN Results AS r2 ON r2.Draw = d.ID AND r2.Number = 22
INNER JOIN Results AS r3 ON r3.Draw = d.ID AND r3.Number = 45
GROUP BY
    d.id;
```

Fred's answer will work, but tbh it's fragile in that it will only work if you are looking for 3 results. My answer is more deliberate, however you will have to construct the query programatically to determine how many joins are necessary to get the results you want, for example:

```
15 -> 1 join
15, 22 -> 2 joins
15, 22, 45 -> 3 joins
....
```

Comment: This returns both Draws not just draws that have all 3 numbers in the result.  It also has a rogue comma after r.* :)

Comment: Rogue has been slain

Comment: Yes @Fred you are right. Mike Purcell thanks for the update. Indeed the query is constructed programmatically in order to work in all cases. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Per your question you don't need a join or anything...

```
select Draw from 
Results r
where r.Number in (15,22,45);
```

Comment: Yeap that was the case since the beginning. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possibility (without duplicates)

```
select * from Draws d where exists (select * from Results r where r.Draw=d.Id and Number in (1, 2, 3...) );
```

Comment: That's a horrible query for something like this... you can just do DISTINCT

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use JOIN for getting this result

```
SELECT * FROM Draw, Results 
WHERE Draw.ID = Results.DrawID 
AND Results.Number IN (15,22,45);
```

**In Result:**

You will get the Results ids
**(2, 3, 5, 7, 8)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Draw FROM Results
Where Number IN (15,22,45)
Group By Draw
Having Count(*) > 2
```

Will give you only Draws that have all 3

```
SELECT d.Date, r.Draw FROM #result r Join #Draws d ON d.id = r.Draw
Where Number IN (15,22,45)
Group By d.Date, r.Draw
Having Count(*) > 2
```

If you want the date in the results.