# Get duplicates really is it a bad query or bad database design?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, distinct

[I have read this article](https://webbtechsolutions.com/2009/07/24/the-effects-of-distinct-in-a-sql-query/)

In the second paragrpah says this:

"The fact that the resultset has duplicates is frequently (though not always) the result of a poor database design, an ineffective query, or both".

Later use as example the Adventures database, that I guess that it has a good design.

Well, my doubt is this case. I have to tables, Persons and Orders and I want to get all persons that has at least one order which total >= $200. I would use this query:

```
Select Persons.* from Persons, Orders where
Orders.IDPerson = Persons.IDPerson
and Orders.Total >= 200;
```

In this case I can get many times the same person because has more than one order which total is 200 or more. Really I want each person once in the results, so is this query a bad query because a I can get the same person many times?

Another option is this query:

```
select * from Person where
IDPerson IN(select IDPerson from Orders where total >= 200);
```

In this case I get only once each person, although this person has more than one order with a total >= 200. But use a subquery to avoid duplicates in the main query is it a good idea?

In this case, Persons and orders, I guess that the database design is not bad, because I don't know which other option I have to design this model, and the query I guess is very simple, but I have the doubt if in this case to get duplicates it is a sign of bad query.

In sumary, get duplicates is a bad query in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Is bad practice NOT to use EXPLICIT `JOIN` :) AdventureWorks design is ok. The first query returns as it should. But you have `1:n` relationship. That is why you get duplicates. If you want only `Persons` data you could add `SELECT DISTINCT Persons.*` but the solution with subquery is slightly better.

Comment: the query(1) is not ineffective but wrong. your question in english is: all persons that has at least one order which total >= $200, your question in sql is: all orders with total >= $200 and who bought them

Comment: Getting Duplicate value means i) Bad DB Design ii) Poor query in this order..I think we should avoid that de-normalization step which lead to duplicate value.I am not saying to avoid de-normalization altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first query is bad like this. Seems not useful to get duplicates which you later need to remove by using DISTINCT.

The seconds query with the sub-query seems more useful in the context (maybe sometimes it makes more sense to use "exists" rather than "in").

[SQL Server IN vs. EXISTS Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance)

Such query would also be possible as well:

```
select * 
from Person
join
(
    select IDPerson
    from Orders 
    where total >= 200  
) PersonsWithMoreThan200Total
on Person.IDPerson = PersonsWithMoreThan200Total.IDPerson
```