# SQL Return only rows that do not contain multiple values in column

Tags: sql, t-sql

Take the below table

| Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| aa | null |
| aa | date |
| aa | null |
| bb | date |
| cc | null |
| cc | null |
| dd | date |
| dd | date |

What I'm looking to return would be the below where col 1 is returned only if col 2 is date only rows with null and date or just null removed.

| Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| bb | date |
| dd | date |
| dd | date |

Comment: Is date here a type or a literal string just saying 'date'?

Comment: Date is a type here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```sql
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM yourTable
WHERE Col1 IN (
    SELECT Col1
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Col1
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'date' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
);
```

The above logic ensures that any matching `Col1` value has only `date` appearing in `Col2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the answer in the question I closed this as a duplicate of, [Select Only Those rows which occur exactly once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682070/select-only-those-rows-which-occur-exactly-once), but uses a conditional `COUNT` instead:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Col1,
           Col2,
           COUNT(CASE Col2 WHEN 'date' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1) AS NonDateCount
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM CTE
WHERE NonDateCount = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ADSis4K1)

Answer (score 0):

As per your table structure please try the below queries:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
```

or Col1 records having date with  counts:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM YOURTABLE
)
SELECT col1,col2, COUNT(*)
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL AND col2 NOT LIKE '%null%' 
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

[image]

| Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| bb | date |
| dd | date |
| dd | date |

Answer (score 0):

Based on the expected outputs, it looks like you're essentially trying to capture all instances of a group with 0 null subgroups. You could use count if there was a target number other than 0 but if the requirement is 0 you can do this.

```
SELECT YT.col1,
       YT.col2
FROM YOURTABLE AS YT
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM YOURTABLE AS YTI
   WHERE YT.COL1  = YTI.Col1 
   AND YTI.Col2 IS NULL
)
```