# Why is evaluating a Django QuerySet in a Boolean context slower than calling `exists` on it?

Tags: python, django

So the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) state the following:

> And to find whether a queryset contains any items:
>
> ```
> if some_queryset.exists():
>     print("There is at least one object in some_queryset")
> ```
>
> Which will be faster than:
>
> ```
> if some_queryset:
>     print("There is at least one object in some_queryset")
> ```

Why is that though? What good reason is there? Often when evaluating a `QuerySet` in a Boolean context, all a user cares about is whether there's at least one item which presumably is why `exists` is faster. Why can't `__bool__` on `QuerySet` simply do the same amount of work as `exists`?

Look at the source code, there seems to be a bit of work involved:

```
def __bool__(self):
    self._fetch_all()
    return bool(self._result_cache)
```

But no documentation providing context on why.

For me, simply calling `if some_queryset:` is much cleaner and more Pythonic.

Comment: You missed the paragraph after the one you've quoted: "Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists() will do more overall work (one query for the existence check plus an extra one to later retrieve the results) than simply using bool(some_queryset), which retrieves the results and then checks if any were returned."

Comment: @DanielRoseman but that's the "how", not the "why", or at least to me it seems that way, I don't understand the need for this difference. If there's was a practical use case on there that clearly illustrated the significance of this distnction, that'd help a lot.

Comment: But it includes the why. This allows you to evaluate the queryset if you know you'll be iterating it later, and avoid that extra query, while leaving `exists()` as the option for when you know you won't be iterating.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Right, so it's just an optimisation shortcut for queries that  just need to be non-empty?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance) answers it.

Comment: @ascripter Is this what Django does under the hood? If so, you're welcome to put it in an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @Nobilis sorry, thought it was easier to prove this and get the query from `.exists()`. You need really dig deep through the source :/

Answer (score 1):

`bool` will be useful when you want to access the data from the queryset at later point of time.
SQL query that will be executed in `if some_queryset:` will be of the type

> SELECT #column_names# FROM #table_name# ...

along with some other conditions depending on your queryset.

While SQL query that  will be executed in `if some_queryset.exists():` will be of the format

> SELECT (1) FROM #table_name# ... LIMIT 1

In this `SELECT (1) ...` returns a column of 1's for every row in the table and `LIMIT` will restrict the lookup to one entry only.

This change in query will have mainly two advantages:

1. Lesser time in query execution
2. Very less data to be transferred over the network