# How to speed up this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, performance, subquery

I am trying to fetch data from a SQL DB via PHPmyAdmin but it takes ages to excute my query. Do you have any idea how to speed up my query ?

My DB has the following structure

Table joueurs

| id_joueur
| mail
|

Table paires

| paires.annee
| idj1
| idj2
|

Thanks alot

```
/* mail from all players being first memeber of a pair (idj1) 
in 2015, 2016 and 2017 and removing doubles*/

SELECT 
    mail
from 
    joueurs 
where 
    (joueurs.id_joueur in
        (SELECT idj1
        FROM paires
        WHERE  (paires.annee = 2015 OR paires.annee = 2016 OR paires.annee = 2017)
        )
    )
GROUP BY mail
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the subquery and just `join` the two tables. And also `where` clause might be better with a condition like `paires.annee > 2014 and paires.annee < 2018`. 
But the only way to improve it is to add indices to the tables.

```
SELECT 
    j.mail
FROM
    joueurs j 
JOIN paires p on p.idj1 = j.id_joueur
WHERE p.annee > 2014 and p.annee < 2018  
GROUP BY j.mail
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Comment: Don't need the `having` clause, as with the [inner] join there will always be at least one. in fact, making it `SELECT DISTINCT` and dropping the group by would do the same thing. If this does not make things faster (which is likely), agree that indexes need to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Exists` on place of in, something like this

```
SELECT 
    j.mail
from 
    joueurs j
where 
   Exists
        (SELECT idj1
        FROM paires
        WHERE  idj1 =j.id_joueur and (paires.annee = 2015 OR paires.annee = 2016 OR paires.annee = 2017  )
        )    
GROUP BY j.mail
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

**EDIT**: 
[SQL Server IN vs. EXISTS Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065329/3953479) here you can read about `Exists` and `IN`

Comment: Thank you Rajeev, but this does not seem to improve performance

Answer (score 0):

My initial recommendation is:

```
select distinct j.mail
from joueurs j
where exists (select 1
              from paires p
              where p.idj1 = j.id_joueur and p.annee in (2015, 2016, 2017)
             );
```

The `having` clause does nothing.  For performance, you want an index on `paires(idj1, annee)`.

If this still takes a long time, what happens if you remove the `distinct`?  Are the results still acceptable?