# SQL Query optimization without Not In and In

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a below query and it is fetching me the required results. But i have read that using NOT IN and IN is not good for performance.

Can one please suggest, what would be the best way to modify this query as EmailLog table contains a lot of data and is there a way i can avoid calling this table twice, to optimize the query performance.

```
Select E.EmployeeID, E.GovtYN From EMployee E
    INNER JOIN RentalAgreement RA
    ON RA.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND RA.DateTo = Cast(DATEADD(day, 21 , 
    GetDate()) As Date)
AND E.EmployeeID NOT IN (
    Select EmployeeID From EmailLog
    Where DateLogged = Cast (GetDate() As Date)  AND TemplateID = 100
)
AND E.EmployeeID IN
(
    Select EmployeeID From EmailLog
    Where DateLogged Between Cast(DateAdd(day, -21, GetDate()) AS Date) AND 
    Cast(GetDate() As Date) AND TemplateID = 200
)
```

I have been trying to fetch all employee details where their rental agreement is about to expire in next 21 days. So for each of the employee record fetched, there would be an entry made in EmailLog table.

So i need to make sure that the same employee record is not picked again on the same day making sure it is not in EmailLog table and i need to verify one more entry on the EmailLog table for the employee saying there is an entry against him in the EmailLog table with the TemplateID = 200, so that only those employee details are fetched.

Comment: Explain the logic that you are tring to implement.  Also, qualify all your column names, to make it clear where data is combing from.

Comment: look into using EXCEPT that might speed you up.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Have updated the reason for the query. Please check if it provides the details

Answer (score 2):

I would write the logic as:

```
select ra.EmployeeID, ra.GovtYN
from RentalAgreement ra
where ra.DateTo = Cast(DATEADD(day, 21, GetDate()) As Date) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from emaillog el
                  where el.EmployeeID = ra.EmployeeID and
                        el.DateLogged = Cast(GetDate() As Date)  
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from emaillog el
              where el.EmployeeID = ra.EmployeeID and
                    el.DateLogged = Cast(dateadd(day, -21, GetDate()) As Date)  
             ) ;
```

Then, I would include indexes on `RentalAgreement(DateTo, EmployeeId)` and `emaillog(EmployeeID, DateLogged)`.

Note that for the query you have in your question, you don't seem to need the `Employee` table.  The only column you are using from that table is the matched column in `RentalAgreement`.

Comment: Confirmed... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance

Comment: @JasonGeiger, that link is very old, and was a little suspect even when it was posted. I wouldn't put a lot of stock in it, unless one is actually using SQL Server 2005 or below.

Comment: Not that I'm questioning Gordon's answer. I'm just saying that the link provided doesn't do anything to confirm the answer.

Comment: The link states that "Exists" is faster than "In".  What are you questioning?  Here is a more detailed explanation using "Not Exists" and "Not In" https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/