# Slow SQL IN Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query. I need information from a table but there are no keys that link these two tables together, and there isn't really a way that it makes sense to reference the other table from either table.

My Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM courses as c 
WHERE c.StartYear = 2016 
AND  c.student_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.student_id 
                      FROM programs AS p 
                      WHERE p.StartYear = 2016 
                      AND p.program_code NOT LIKE "M%")
```

This Query takes about 5 seconds to execute, which is way too long. Is there a better way to do this?

Server: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.35

Comment: What server?   And post query plan.

Comment: Would you be so kind to [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) this?

Comment: You say there is no way to link them together, yet they both have a `student_id` and in effect you ***are*** joining the results using that key?  Also, if `courses` contains a `student_id`, I take it you're counting student-course combinations, rather than counting courses or counting students?

Comment: Do you have the indexes? It doesn't really need to have a link but that doesn't mean they shouldn't have indexes on the fields you search.

Comment: @MatBailie The Programs table can have multiple student Id entries and so can the courses table. They don't relate to each other. I've tried INNER and LEFT joining them but that takes 10 seconds or longer.

Comment: @SimonChawla - Define "they don't relate to each other" because in your example query you've intimated they ***do*** relate to each other...  You specifically say `WHERE c.student_id IN ( <list of p.student_id> )`  That's almost exactly a join on `student_id`...  Perhaps you would benefit from showing us a dumy set of dat with the expected results that you're looking for?

Comment: Please post the table schema and the indexes that you have on the columns. Those will really help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the exact same results, and may or may not be faster, but does demonstrate that at present your query ***does*** intimate that the two tables can be related by `student_id`.

If the query below is logically incorrect, so is your example query, and you should give a dummy example to demonstrate the logic you want : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  courses    c
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    student_id,
    startYear
  FROM
    programs
  WHERE
    program_code NOT LIKE "M%"
  GROUP BY
    student_id,
    startYear
)
  p
    ON  p.student_id = c.student_id
    AND p.startYear  = c.startYear
WHERE
  c.StartYear = 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exists

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM courses as c 
 WHERE c.StartYear = 2016 
   and exists (SELECT 1
                 FROM programs AS p 
                WHERE p.StartYear = 2016 
                  AND p.program_code NOT LIKE "M%" 
                  and c.student_id = p.student_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exists` should work better than `In` clause, so you can try this query. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance) for related discussion.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM courses as c 
WHERE c.StartYear = 2016 
AND Exists (SELECT 1
            FROM programs AS p 
            WHERE p.StartYear = 2016 
            AND student_id = c.student_id
            AND p.program_code NOT LIKE "M%")
```

Comment: Thank for the related discussion. I read through it and I have tried this, but it really does take twice as long