# Multi not like expression sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So basically i've a table like this.

```
+--------+----------+   
|   name |  Group   |  
+--------+----------+   
|   xxxx |   1      |  
|   yyyy |   1      |  
|   xxxx |   2      |  
|   yyyy |   3      |  
|   xxxx |   4      |  
+--------+----------+
```

and i don't want to display any records that have name xxxx in their group.

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: Give this a try. select * from <table> where name <> 'xxxx'

Comment: Edit the question & add your desired result.

Comment: So you only want to show the row in Group 3? because grps 1,2 and 4 all contains something with xxxx as a name?

Comment: It's primitive example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.group = t.group and t1.name = 'xxxx')
```

Comment: your awswer seem to be right but i got some problem with it cause im using CTE and  my query after CTE implementation looks like this                                                         SELECT DISTINCT c.TWG_Kod as NAME, g1.TwG_Kod as GROUP, k.twr_nazwa, m.MAG_Nazwa, m.MAG_Kod 
   
FROM CTE c join cdn.TwrGrupy g1 with (nolock) on c.TwG_GIDNumer = g1.TwG_GrONumer. And i don't know how to manage to use it in your querry cause of column name duplication

Answer (score -1):

You need a subquery at first to identify groups you do not need. then you need to filter it from main query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
Where group not in ( select group from Table1 where name != 'xxxx')
```

Comment: I would avoid using `IN()` while I can use `EXISTS()`

Comment: why? they both have usage areas. I think this is very wide topic to be discussed here

Comment: Why? ok [see why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance).

Comment: @Sami *"This used to be true but in current versions (at least 2008) the optimizer is much smarter... it actually treats IN () just like an EXISTS ()"*...

Comment: @NickA Well, the OP did not specify the version yet :)

Comment: but the answer is totally correct and it does not deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: @Sami I like to think not pre-2008 :)

Comment: Many find the `NOT IN` result when there are null values returned from the sub-query a bit surprising.