# the maximum limit of items a 'In' clause can handle

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

what are the limits of data i can pass to a database in a programing language(like php).
suppose i have 1 million records in my database and I have 1 million data in my hand which i want to do a exist checking. if i used a query like

```
 select id from table where id in (array of 1 million data)
```

what will happen? will this request even reach database?
if it reaches, what are the posibilities ,will it returns a data a better speed than a million querys to db searching id's or a full select data call with  millions of  for loops.

just for curiosity!.

Comment: we do something like that using .net, we bulk insert the values to a staging table, then do ....IN (SELECT ID FROM tab...) Not so many as 1 million though, but it could still work ok

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a specific number, however, the documentation specifies you'll likely to have problems once you have "thousands" of values. [IN (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

> Explicitly including an extremely large number of values (many
>   thousands of values separated by commas) within the parentheses, in an
>   IN clause can consume resources and return errors 8623 or 8632. To
>   work around this problem, store the items in the IN list in a table,
>   and use a SELECT subquery within an IN clause.
>
> Error 8623:
>
> *The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.*
>
> Error 8632:
>
> *Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try
>   to simplify them.*

To quote my comment I made:

If you need to pass a large number of values to a query, I suggest a Table-Type parameter. But if you really need to pass 1M+ values then it sounds like something is wrong with your design. You may even be better off listing the values you don't want.

*Edit: To add to my comment, many (including myself) prefer to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. So instead of a query like:*

```
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE YT.YourColumn IN (SELECT OT.YourColumn
                        FROM OtherTable OT)
```

*You would have the query:*

```
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OtherTable OT
              WHERE OT.YourColumn = YT.YourColumn)
```

Comment: what about the second question which is the best approach to check a 1m data to another 1 m data in db

Comment: The answer covers that @jithink, the documentation states *"store the items in the IN list in a table, and use a SELECT subquery within an IN clause."* and I state *"If you need to pass a large number of values to a query, I suggest a Table-Type parameter"*. Personally, i also prefer using `EXISTS` over `IN`.

Comment: @jithink I'd used `EXISTS`. See these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance), [2](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/), [3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists) for some interesting debate on performance and comparisons.