# Find a value from table that is only unique to one id

Tags: sql

I have a table "**stats**" that consists **3 ids**.

**IDs:** id_seller, id_part and id_proj

From this table, I want to find projects (**id_proj**) which buy specific parts (**id_part**) that is avaiable **only from** one seller.

**In other words:** **Find id_proj**, which buy id_parts, which are avaiable **only from one seller** (seller S5 is the only seller that sells P2).

[image]

So, In this example **id_part (P2)** is the only part id, that is specific and it is selling just to **id_seller (S5)**.

**The return should be: J2, J4**

I ve tried with something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id_proj
FROM stats s
WHERE NOT id_part IN (
  SELECT s2.id_part
  FROM stats s2
  WHERE s2.id_seller = 'S5');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct id_proj from stats 
where id_part in
 (SELECT s.id_part
 FROM stats s
 WHERE s.id_seller = 'S5'
and id_part not in (select id_part from stats where id_seller <> 'S5') --**this  take only part from seller S5**
   )
```

if this is a homework though you should really understand the concept of IN and NOT IN [like in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance), EXIST and NOT EXIST.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Group By` with `Having` . Group by **id_part** and select pieces that have a seller.

Then `join` the result to the main table to get the information you need.

```
SELECT s2.*
FROM
    (SELECT id_part,max(id_seller) AS id_seller
    FROM stats
    GROUP BY id_part
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_seller) = 1) s1
JOIN stats s2 ON s1.id_part = s2.id_part AND s1.id_seller = s2.id_seller
```