# Don't select rows where column A is duplicated AND any row of column B is a specific value

Tags: sql, database

I'm working on generating a report merging multiple tables. The report requires only showing projects that did not have any document marked 'Not Received' These document markings are listed in a table that lists each document in an individual line. So when merged into my other table it creates multiple rows of the same project. For example the following table

| Project Number | ChecklistValue |
| --- | --- |
| 565 | Received |
| 565 | Not Received |
| 465 | Received |
| 465 | Not Applicable |

As you can see really only two projects are listed on this table but the desired output is:

| Project Number | Other Info |
| --- | --- |
| 465 | etc |

I do not need the checklist value on the actual report, so I can use the `GROUP BY` to combine all the good rows, but where I have an Issue is that would still include project 565 even if I include something like where `ChecklistValue <> 'Not Received'`, 565 needs to be hidden from the report entirely because any row for 565 contains 'Not Received'.

So that's my actual question, how do I exclude all project numbers rows that have any row containing 'Not Received'?

I'm adding the entire query will generalized names below:

```
SELECT 
Project Number
,Name
,Contractor
,ABS(DATEDIFF(day,(ActualDate),(EstDate))) AS DelayPeriod
,S.NoteDate
,S.FinalAppDate
,Status
,S.ONE
,S.TWO
,S.THREE
,S.FOUR
,CH.ChecklistValue
FROM [DB1] A
INNER JOIN [DB2] C ON A.Contractor = C.Contractor
INNER JOIN [DB3] S ON A.AppID = S.AppID
INNER JOIN [DB4] LS ON S.StatusID = LS.StatusID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB5] CH ON A.AppID = CH.AppID AND CH.OtherID = 1
WHERE C.TypeID = 4 AND A.YEAR = 2022, AND S.THING = 1 AND
(CH.CheckListValue IS NULL OR A.AppID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM [DB5] WHERE
CheckListValue = 'Not Reveived'))
GROUP BY Project Number,Name,Contractor,ABS(DATEDIFF(day,(ActualDate),(EstDate))) AS DelayPeriod,S.NoteDate,S.FinalAppDate,Status,S.ONE,S.TWO,S.THREE,S.FOUR
```

The last portion of the `WHERE` clause was added from a suggestion, but I'm clearly not implementing it correctly as it errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not in` like:

```sql
create table test(
  num int,
  description varchar(20)
);
insert into test(num,description)
values(565,'Received'),
(565,'Not Received'),
(465,'Received'),
(465,'Not Applicable');

select *
from test
where num not in
(
  select num -- Only select one column here
  from test
  where description = 'Not Received'
);
```

Results:

```
+-----+---------------+
| num | description   |
+-----+---------------+
| 465 | Received      |
| 465 | Not Applicable|
+-----+---------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5535191b132be38e06916b84cb9b1d4) this is on `sql-server` but works on other `dbms` as well.

So in your query you should have (in my understanding):

```sql
OR A.AppID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT AppID -- Not select *
    FROM [DB5] 
    WHERE CheckListValue = 'Not Reveived'
)
```

---

Other way to do it is with a `cte` but it is complicated at first glance:

```sql
with x as(
  select num
  from test
  where description = 'Not Received'
)
select t.num, t.description
from test t
left join x
on t.num = x.num
where x.num is null
```

I'm first creating a `cte` on the num column `where` the description = *not received* then I'm selecting all from the test table, and I'm `left join`ing to the `cte` **but** I'm only selecting the num column that are **not** in the `cte` by using `where x.num is null`, and this will only return `465`.

Now which one is better? I don't know sometimes `join` would be faster and sometimes `in`, for more you can find on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72692455/16019058).

Comment: I added the query to my original post, because I tried this but I get `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS` but I dont have the sql experience to address this issue

Comment: Are you selecting more than one column in subquery?

Comment: oh god, yeah that's exactly what I did, I tried copying the example sub query you wrote, abut I transposed the two select clauses on accident.