# I am getting this answer "WHERE clause should return type BOOL, but returns INT64 at [7:3]"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name
FROM 
  bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations
WHERE
  (
    SELECT
      start_station_id
    FROM
     bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    WHERE
      usertype = 'subscriber'
  )
```

I am new to learning SQL, so I don't know what the error is trying to tell. It my first time doing subquery within a query, so I want to say is about the space otherwise I don't know. I BigQuery to practice SQL.

Comment: `where (select...) = `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a subquery in the WHERE section without a comparison. In the WHERE section you should have `something operator something` that is for example: `someTableField = 'someValue'` The error is trying to say that there is no logical check to return a boolean type, that is whether the comparison in the where section will be true or false.

Based on your query alone it should probably something like:

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name
FROM 
  bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations
WHERE
 citibike_stations.start_station_id IN (
    SELECT
      start_station_id
    FROM
     bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    WHERE
      usertype = 'subscriber'
  )
```

In the where section above what I did was comparing whether the field `start_station_id` from table `citibike_stations` on your `from` section is within your subquery on the `citibike_trips` table.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part in explaining the WHERE section. Subqueries are new to me.

Comment: @Tails0298 glad to be of help. If this answer was helpful to you please consider marking it as accepted. It is the V icon on the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

A `where` clause is a condition on the `select`, that it should only return when some column = some value, but in your case you don't specify the value it should check on.

Perhaps you mean to say:

```sql
SELECT station_id, name
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations
WHERE station_id in
(
    SELECT start_station_id
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    WHERE usertype = 'subscriber'
)
```

But better way at least in [my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72692455/16019058) would be using `join` like:

```sql
SELECT station_id, name
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations s
join bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips t
on t.start_station_id = s.station_id
WHERE t.usertype = 'subscriber'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. I doing the Google Data Analytics Certificate and did not quite understand why it could give me information. It is easier to loose focus when you are focusing in something else.

Answer (score 0):

The where command works like if in programming. You must compare two expressions using conditional operators. Your query only performs a calculation and finally produces an output of start_station_id and does not perform any kind of comparison.
To correct this, you must compare the result with another expression. For example, checking the presence of a station_id in the final result like the code below

```
SELECT 
  station_id, 
  name 
FROM 
  bigquery - public - data.new_york.citibike_stations 
WHERE 
  station_id in (
    SELECT 
      start_station_id 
    FROM 
      bigquery - public - data.new_york.citibike_trips 
    WHERE 
      usertype = 'subscriber'
  )
```